# Does clang/libclang have Java bindings?

Tags: java, c++, plugins, ide, clang

I would like to use the code analysis capabilities of clang in a plugin for a Java-based IDE.

Since the plugin must be written in Java, I am wondering whether there are any Java bindings for libclang, or some other way to access clang functionality from a Java program (beyond using JNI directly)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm closely tracking LLVM/Clang development and i'm not aware of Java bindings to libclang.

Comment: This was in '11; has anything changed since then? (I guess not since I haven't found anything but...)

Comment: Yep, nothing beyond `jclang` which haven't seen updated for 4 years.

Comment: 2022 now. Has anything changed?